# Responsive Calendar for Bootstrap 3

Tags: mobile, responsive-design, fullcalendar, twitter-bootstrap-3

My website uses Bootstrap 3 for the GUI. Since Bootstrap is mobile first I am trying to make the whole website usable on smartphones too. However I am using Fullcalendar and unfortunately this is not usable on device-width of 320px - it is just too wide. Is there a responsive calendar alternative for that use case?

Comment: I disagree with closing this question.  This is a very legitimate issue for those who are transitioning to Bootstrap 3.

Answer (score 2):

What do you expect and what are your requirements?
The example page of Fullcalendar (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) shows a calendar build up in a html table. The table has a 100% width for columns. The width of the demo is set to 810 by wrapping it in a container div. When the width setting of this container has been disabled, you could resize the calendar to very small, see:

[image]

Maybe the size make it not useful on a touch screen.

[Multi Dates Picker Bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397675/multi-dates-picker-bug/18433458) refers to Multidatespicker based on jQuery IU (too). This views also seems to fit 320px;

Comment: Personally, I find FullCalendar pretty useless on mobile devices. As you can see in your example, the titles get squished to the point of being unreadable and the table cells get a bit funky in size.